# why Whereis not able to show command path, while which is working correctly?

Tags: bash, path, which

I have created a executable bash shell script file command. I added directory path of my custom command to `$PATH` variable, but `whereis` not showing the command path but `which` shows correctly. I am using bash shell with `ubuntu 14.04`

Added `.local/bin` to `$PATH` where custom command resides in `.bashrc`

```
~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/rahul/.local/bin
```

custom command file exists and is with executable flag

```
~$ ls -l .local/bin/
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rahul employee 79 Dec 13 15:47 customCC
```

`whereis` failing to locate the command

```
~$ whereis customCC
customCC:
```

`which` is able to find the command.

```
~$ which customCC
/home/rahul/.local/bin/customCC
```

Bash customCC script code

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/rahul/sample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereis` searches a hard-coded path, unless instructed otherwise, while `which` searches the PATH variable in the current environment. Please read the manual for both commands.

You could use `whereis` with this syntax:

```
whereis -B $HOME/.local/bin -f customCC
```

Comment: Some versions differ: [example](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whereis.1.html).

Comment: @Thomas Dickey- The question specified ubuntu14.04-[whereis](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/whereis.1.html) .